# Conditionally render a component based on ajax event of another component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new to JSF and I'm trying to write a simple DB Explorer using PrimeFaces and Wildfly. I want a Tree component for browsing the data, with a GridPanel to show details when something is selected from the tree. Nothing too complex, just to get grips with syntax and logic.

My problem is this: when I select something from the tree, the callback method is correctly called in the ManagedBean, but the GridPanel does not show up. It's bound to be shown when the selected value in the ManagedBeans is not null.

index.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Media Explorer</title>
    <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    <style>
.ui-tree {
    width: 860px;
}
</style>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Media Explorer"
            resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">

        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" resizable="false"
            closable="false" collapsible="false">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="900" header="Media List"
            resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true">
            <h:form>
                <p:tree value="#{treeBasicView.root}" var="node" dynamic="true"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeBasicView.singleSelectedTreeNode}">
                    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                        collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                    <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-document">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                    <p:treeNode type="image" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-image">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                    <p:treeNode type="video" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-video">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeBasicView.onNodeSelect}" />
                    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeBasicView.onNodeExpand}" />
                    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{treeBasicView.onNodeCollapse}" />
                    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{treeBasicView.onNodeUnSelect}" />
                </p:tree>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Preview"
            resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true" effect="drop">


        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Media Info">

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="${!empty treeBasicView.singleSelectedTreeNode}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:graphicImage value="art/icon.jpg" width="200" />
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputText value="Title:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{treeBasicView.selected.title}" />

                <h:outputText value="Path:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{treeBasicView.selected.path}" />

                <h:outputText value="Filename:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{treeBasicView.selected.fileName}" />

                <h:outputText value="Size:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{treeBasicView.selected.sizeInBytes}" />
            </p:panelGrid>

        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>

</h:body>
</html>
```

BasicView.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.primefaces.event.NodeCollapseEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.NodeExpandEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.NodeUnselectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

import db.DBHelper;
import entity.Category;
import entity.File;
import entity.Media;

@ManagedBean(name = "treeBasicView")
@SessionScoped

public class BasicView implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode singleSelectedTreeNode;

    public TreeNode getSingleSelectedTreeNode() {
        return singleSelectedTreeNode;
    }

    public void setSingleSelectedTreeNode(TreeNode singleSelectedTreeNode) {
        this.singleSelectedTreeNode = singleSelectedTreeNode;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);

        // POPULATE THE TREE

    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public File getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(File selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {

        this.singleSelectedTreeNode = event.getTreeNode();

    }

    public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {
        String node = event.getTreeNode().getData().toString();
        logger.debug(node);
    }

    public void onNodeCollapse(NodeCollapseEvent event) {
        String node = event.getTreeNode().getData().toString();
        logger.debug(node);
    }

    public void onNodeUnSelect(NodeUnselectEvent event) {
        String node = event.getTreeNode().getData().toString();
        logger.debug(node);
    }

}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're in your `<p:ajax>` indeed nowhere instructing JSF to update the desired component. How should JSF know which parts of the view you'd like to update?

Comment: When you use `rendered` attribute in jsf, it works only on page load. Even if some parameters change after load (`treeBasicView.singleSelectedTreeNode` in your case), page or any elements will not update content. So, to do what you want, you should use ajax call (`<p:ajax>` in Primefaces) to update elements without page reload.

Comment: Thanks to you both, that did it.